# Cannot use AL_FORMAT_STEREO_FLOAT32?

Tags: c++, audio, audio-recording, openal

I'm using the latest version of OpenAL Soft and I'm trying to record using FLOAT32.

```
        capture_device = alcCaptureOpenDevice(NULL, 48000, AL_FORMAT_STEREO_FLOAT32, 48000);
```

However, it fails and I'm forced to fall back to:

```
        capture_device = alcCaptureOpenDevice(NULL, 48000, AL_FORMAT_STEREO16, 48000);
```

Is there something special I need to do in order to get `AL_FORMAT_STEREO_FLOAT32` working?

My sound card supports 24 bit audio and I need to record from it using at least that quality.

Comment: +1 for any low level audio questions. This stuff is not easy to figure out.